# PHP Including a config file multiple times

Tags: php, include

I have a config.php file that creates an array, something like

```
$config = array(
       'foo' => 'bar'
);
function foo()
{
       echo 'good';
}
```

I also have another utility.php file that prints stuff, that depends on config.php

```
require_once(-the absolute path to config.php-);
class Utility{
  function bar()
  {
    echo count($config);
    echo foo();
  }
}
```

I am in a situation where my index.php script depends on config.php as well as utility.php.
Therefore, when I include foo.php I am including config.php again. Something like

```
require_once(-the absolute path to config.php-);
require_once(-the absolute path to utility.php-);
echo count($config);
utility::bar();
```

This function prints out

```
1good
```

However, when I attempt to call Utility::bar, it prints 0 for count($config) - the $config array never gets created in utility.php, in spite of count($config) returning 1 in index.php. Interestingly, calling function foo() in utility.php still returns "good".
Making $config global didn't change anything (and I hear is bad style).

Comment: Variable scope, [here is some reading in the manual for you](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a variable scope issue. Read about PHP variable scope. As an example I think if you changed

```
echo count($config);
```

to

```
global $config;
echo count($config);
```

it would work.